# Fast split of XML document into data.frames by xpath expression

Tags: r, xml, xpath, libxml2, xml2

I wrote a function to split (large) heterogenous XML files into data frames, where the split is done by an xpath expression. By heterogenous I mean that items of interest fall into a set of different "column" structures. However, for larg**ish** XML files, say 50K items and 5 types, the code seems more "sluggish" than I'd expect.

The question is then: is there existing functionality to do this that I missed, and if not, is there an obvious way of improving the speed of the code below?

Here's a minimal example of the kind of XML structure I'm considering:

```
xmldoc <- xml2::read_xml(
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <resp>

     <respMeta>
       <status>200</status>
       <!-- ... -->    
     </respMeta>

     <content>
       <list>
         <item>
           <Type>Type1</Type>
           <ColA>Foo</ColA>
           <ColB>Bar</ColB>
         </item>
         <item>
           <Type>Type2</Type>
           <ColC>Baz</ColC>
         </item>
         <item>
           <Type>Type3</Type>
           <ColA>Lorem</ColA>
           <ColB>Ipsum</ColB>
           <ColC>Dolor</ColC>
         </item>
       </list>
       <!-- ... many many more entries here -->
     </content>

   </resp>')
```

The goal is to convert this to *N* data frames, where *N* is the number of unique values in `//item/Type` (which is unknown at parse time).

Here's my implementation:

```
#' Split XML Document into Dataframes by Xpath Expression
#'
#' @param xml An (xml2) xml document object.
#'
#' @param xpath the path to the values to split by. \code{xml_text} is used
#'   to get the value.
#'
#' @importFrom xml2 xml_text xml_find_all xml_find_first xml_children xml_name
#' @importFrom stats setNames
#' @importFrom dplyr bind_cols
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#'
#' @return list of data frames (tbl_df)
#'
#' @export
xml_to_dfs <- function(xml, xpath)
{
  u <- xml_find_all(xml, xpath) %>% xml_text %>% unique %>% sort

  select <- paste0(xpath, "[. ='", u, "']/..") %>% setNames(u)

  paths <-
    lapply(select, . %>% xml_find_first(x = xml) %>% xml_children %>% xml_name)

  queries <- Map(paste, select, paths, MoreArgs = list(sep = "/"))

  columns <-
    lapply(queries, . %>% lapply(. %>% xml_find_all(x = xml) %>% xml_text))

  Map(setNames, columns, paths) %>% lapply(bind_cols)
}
```

The result of the minimal example, with only one row in each frame, is then:

```
xml_to_dfs(xmldoc, "//item/Type") 
$Type1
# A tibble: 1 × 3
   Type  ColA  ColB
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Type1   Foo   Bar

$Type2
# A tibble: 1 × 2
   Type  ColC
  <chr> <chr>
1 Type2   Baz

$Type3
# A tibble: 1 × 4
   Type  ColA  ColB  ColC
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Type3 Lorem Ipsum Dolor
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
require(xml2)
require(purrr)

oc <- read_xml("path-to-xml-file")
xml_find_all(doc, ".//item") %>% 
  map(xml_children) %>% 
  map(~as_tibble(t(set_names(xml_text(.), xml_name(.))))) #or map_df
```

I would even go for `map_df` in the last line which gives you:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
   Type  ColA  ColB  ColC
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Type1   Foo   Bar  <NA>
2 Type2  <NA>  <NA>   Baz
3 Type3 Lorem Ipsum Dolor
```

P.S.: This is also related to: https://github.com/hadley/purrr/issues/255

Comment: For me the speed with your solution and my solution is almost exactly the same, ~20secs. Your solution is shorter, so +1 for that; but would need some post processing too, as the result should be a list of dfs, with only the columns relevant for each type (this should be fast enough though).